# How to get the location of every pub in Britan?

Tags: address

Someone managed to draw a map of the UK - using only the locations of pubs!

Alas, I have been unable to contact them. Does anyone know the source of their data? I would like to have the lat/long and/or street address of every pub in the uk for a new project.

[image]

Comment: Do you plan to visit them all?

Comment: I have a cunning plan ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says: *Data: OpenStreetMap* in the image.

You can [download OpenStreetMap data dumps](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/17/where-can-i-download-a-dump-of-openstreetmap-data) in a variety of formats, such as shape-files.  Like a database, it will contain nodes of certain types, including one for pubs.  They will all include geographic coordinates.  Simply extract all the nodes that are pubs and you're there.

Comment: How did I miss that? It looks like I can just use http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dpub

Comment: A good way of visually checking if a pub is present is using OpenCycleMap.org as that tends to show them more prominently than other renderings.